# How to bring up printers menu in c# with a button?

Tags: c#, printing, windows-runtime

im building an app which makes it possible to print. I've managed to make it work the only thing i can't figure out is how to add code to a button so the button brings up the side menu with the available printers.

Comment: Are you using Windows RT?

Comment: Yes i am, i also saw that the print dialog brings up a window. This is not what i meant, i wanted to have the printers in the side(charm)menu.

Comment: (I added a Windows RT tag to the question to make it more obvious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dlg = new PrintDialog();
dlg.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: If i add it to my button it comes up with this error: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'PrintDialog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I thought it is a WinForms application. If not, try to reference `System.Windows.Forms` in your project

Comment: i can't if i type system.windows. intellisense says my only available option is system.windows.input

Comment: Yeah you can't do this if it's Windows RT

Comment: Is there antoher option? Or isn't it possible at all?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about Windows RT :(